# Prove that $\int_{0}^\infty (e^{As})^T e^{As}\,ds$ is convergent

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Consider A to be a matrix that has all eigenvalues $\lambda$ with negative real part, that is, $Re(\lambda) < 0$.

a) Show that the integral  $\int_{0}^\infty (e^{As})^T e^{As}\,ds$ is convergent, where $(e^{As})^T$ is the transpose of $e^{As}$.

b) If $C=\int_{0}^\infty (e^{As})^T e^{As}\,ds$, show that $CA +A^tC=-I$

Hint: Integrate both sides of $\frac{d}{ds} ((e^{As})^T e^{As})= (e^{As})^T e^{As}A+A^T(e^{As})^T e^{As}$ for $s$ varying from $0$ to $\infty$.

Could someone help with letter a, please? Thanks!!

Comment: The first part should be easily done by using the operator $2$-norm of matrices.  Convergence follows from the completeness of this norm.

Comment: Could you write this,please? I can not get exactly what you mean. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The second part is easier, we'll start with that.  We begin by noting that
$$
\frac{d}{ds} ((e^{As})^T e^{As})= (e^{As})^T e^{As}A+A^T(e^{As})^T e^{As}
$$
Integrating the left side, we have
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{d}{ds} ((e^{As})^T e^{As})\,ds = 
\left.
(e^{As})^T e^{As}
\right|_0^\infty = 
\lim_{s \to \infty} (e^{As})^T e^{As} - 
(e^{A(0)})^T e^{A(0)}
$$
However, by the continuity of the exponential map, we know that $\lim_{s \to \infty} (e^{As})^T e^{As} = 0$.  So, the left side is simply $-(e^{A(0)})^T e^{A(0)} = -I$.

Integrating the other side, we have
$$
\int_0^\infty \left[(e^{As})^T e^{As}A+A^T(e^{As})^T e^{As}\right]ds =\\ 
\left[\int_0^\infty(e^{As})^T e^{As}ds\right]A+A^T\left[ \int_0^\infty (e^{As})^T e^{As}ds\right]
$$
Setting the two integrated sides equal, we have the desired result.

---

For part (a), let $\|\cdot\|$ denote any matrix norm (such as the spectral norm). It suffices for us to show that
$$
\int_0^\infty \left\|(e^{As})^Te^{(As)}\right\|\,ds < \infty
$$
let $a > 0$ denote the smallest value $-\text{Re}(\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.  Note that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left\|(e^A)^n \right\|^{1/n} = e^{-a} < 1
$$
The same applies to $A^T$.
Fix $\epsilon \in (e^{-a},1)$.
Let $n_0$ be such that $\left\|(e^A)^n \right\|^{1/n}, \left\|([e^A]^T)^n \right\|^{1/n} < \epsilon$ for $n > n_0$.

We then note that

$$
\int_0^\infty \left\|(e^{As})^Te^{(As)}\right\|\,ds =\\
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{(k-1)n_0}^{kn_0} \left\|(e^{As})^Te^{(As)}\right\|\,ds \leq \\
\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\left\|e^{(An_0)}\right\|
\left\|(e^{(An_0)})^T\right\|\right)^{(k-1)}\right)
\int_{0}^{n_0} 
\left\|(e^{A(s)})^T\right\|
\left\|e^{(A(s))}\right\|\,ds 
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Could you help me with letter a, please?

Comment: I have something down for letter (a) now, after a lot of glitches.  Hopefully this makes sense.  Let me know if you need clarification

Comment: Thak you VERY much. You've been so kind!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: Could you help me with this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633818/p-periodic-solution-for-ode-system